# Scala Newb Question - about scoping and variables

Tags: scala, scoping

I'm parsing XML, and keep finding myself writing code like:

```
val xml = <outertag>
<dog>val1</dog>
<cat>val2</cat>
</outertag>

var cat = ""
var dog = ""

for (inner <- xml \ "_") {
  inner match {
    case <dog>{ dg @ _* }</dog> => dog = dg(0).toString()
    case <cat>{ ct @ _* }</cat> => cat = ct(0).toString()
  }
}

/* do something with dog and cat */
```

It annoys me because I should be able to declare cat and dog as val (immutable), since I only need to set them once, but I have to make them mutable. And besides that it just seems like there must be a better way to do this in scala. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two (now make it *three*) possible solutions. The first one is pretty quick and dirty. You can run the whole bit in the Scala interpreter.

```
val xmlData = <outertag>
<dog>val1</dog>
<cat>val2</cat>
</outertag>

// A very simple way to do this mapping.
def simpleGetNodeValue(x:scala.xml.NodeSeq, tag:String) = (x \\ tag).text

val cat = simpleGetNodeValue(xmlData, "cat")
val dog = simpleGetNodeValue(xmlData, "dog")
```

`cat` will be "val2", and `dog` will be "val1".

Note that if either node is not found, an empty string will be returned. You can work around this, or you could write it in a slightly more idiomatic way:

```
// A more idiomatic Scala way, even though Scala wouldn't give us nulls.
// This returns an Option[String].
def getNodeValue(x:scala.xml.NodeSeq, tag:String) = {
  (x \\ tag).text match {
    case "" => None
    case x:String => Some(x)
  }
}

val cat1 = getNodeValue(xmlData, "cat") getOrElse "No cat found."
val dog1 = getNodeValue(xmlData, "dog") getOrElse "No dog found."
val goat = getNodeValue(xmlData, "goat") getOrElse "No goat found."
```

`cat1` will be "val2", `dog1` will be "val1", and `goat` will be "No goat found."

**UPDATE**: Here's one more convenience method to take a list of tag names and return their matches as a Map[String, String].

```
// Searches for all tags in the List and returns a Map[String, String].
def getNodeValues(x:scala.xml.NodeSeq, tags:List[String]) = {
  tags.foldLeft(Map[String, String]()) { (a, b) => a(b) = simpleGetNodeValue(x, b)}
}

val tagsToMatch = List("dog", "cat")
val matchedValues = getNodeValues(xmlData, tagsToMatch)
```

If you run that, `matchedValues` will be `Map(dog -> val1, cat -> val2)`.

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE 2**: Per Daniel's suggestion, I'm using the double-backslash operator, which will descend into child elements, which may be better as your XML dataset evolves.

Comment: I sense someone has been working quite a bit with XML lately... :-) However, I propose you use double backslash instead of single backslash in the first example. (damned stackoverflow keep messing with the backslashes)

Comment: I haven't really been working much with XML - I'm just trying to get a feel for Scala.  In any case, I'm trying to clean up the easier questions so you can answer the doozies, like some weird Python conversion.

Comment: Good call on the double-backslash, by the way. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val xml = <outertag><dog>val1</dog><cat>val2</cat></outertag>
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <outertag><dog>val1</dog><cat>val2</cat></outertag>

scala> val cat = xml \\ "cat" text
cat: String = val2

scala> val dog = xml \\ "dog" text
dog: String = val1
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider wrapping up the XML inspection and pattern matching in a function that returns the multiple values you need as a tuple (`Tuple2[String, String]`). But stop and consider: it looks like it's possible to not match any `dog` and `cat` elements, which would leave you returning null for one or both of the tuple components. Perhaps you could return a tuple of `Option[String]`, or throw if either of the element patterns fail to bind.

In any case, you can generally solve these initialization problems by wrapping up the constituent statements into a function to yield an expression. Once you have an expression in hand, you can initialize a constant with the result of its evaluation.

Comment: Thanks! Can you show an example using a yield expression? Or at least a good url that talks about them. Like I said, I'm a newb =)

Comment: That wasn't quite what I meant. By defining a function that returns a value -- here, a Tuple2[String, String] -- you now have an expression available, because calling a function that returns a value is an expression. Declaring and initializing a "val" is itself a statement, and the right hand side (the initial value) must be an expression, not a statement. That means that the right hand side can be a literal value, or a function invocation, but it can't be one or more statements. It's this distinction between statements and expressions that often encourages on to write these small functions.